# TypeError: this.props.logout is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Sending props in render method from Login class but Admin class is not able to read the props passed.
Neither the logout method nor the state variable isAuthenticated are being read by the Admin class.

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor...

    handleLogin...//Function

    logout...//Function

    render(){
        if(!this.state.isAuthenticated){
        return (
        <div className="login-wrapper">
            <Route path="/admin" render={(e)=><Admin isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} logout={this.logout.bind(this)}></Admin>}></Route>
            <div className="login"> 
                <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID" value={this.state.id} onChange={(e)=>this.setState({id:e.target.value})}/>
                <br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={(e)=>this.setState({password:e.target.value})}/>
                <br/>
                <button type="submit" onClick={(e)=>{this.handleLogin(e)}}>Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
        }
        else{
            return(
            <div>
            <Route path="/admin" render={(e)=><Admin isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} logout={this.logout.bind(this)}></Admin>}></Route>
            <Redirect to="/admin"></Redirect>
            </div>
        )}
}
}
```

Admin class shows this.props.logout() is not a function.

```
class Admin extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={};
    }

    render(){ 
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                   <div id="menu">
                        <button onClick={(e)=>{this.props.logout()}}>Logout</button>
                   </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215749/discussion-on-question-by-hardik-aswal-typeerror-this-props-logout-is-not-a-fun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so I think you've got the approach slightly wrong

You shouldn't be rendering this:

```
          <Route
            path="/admin"
            render={e => (
              <Admin
                isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                logout={this.logout}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Redirect to="/admin" />
```

in the Logout component

all you need to do is move this code:

```
  logout = e => {
    console.log("Logging out...");
    localStorage.removeItem("admin");
    this.setState({
      isAuthenticated: false
    });
  };
```

to the `App.js` file and then pass down `logout` to this route: `<Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />`

like so: `<Route path="/admin" component={Admin} logout={this.logout}/>`

you also need to put `isAuthenticated` in the state of that component

you should have ALL your `Route`s living in the same place and if you need to go to a different route in a different component then use `<Link />`

let me know if that helps

Comment: @HardikAswal haha no worries mate! glad we solved it. let me know if you need help on anything else. have a good day :)

Comment: Just one more question, now that I have logged out the user by deleting the token as you as in the logout function, all I have to do now is use an if-else block to know whether user is authenticated or not right? If yes, return the admin page, If not, redirect to the login page. Is that correct?

Comment: take a look at this: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/. it's what I followed for my application. basically wrap all routes as `public` or `protected` and in the `protected` routes, user will be redirected to a different page  if they not authenticated